# Save dynamically loaded webpage

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, web, web-crawler

This should be an easy task but I couldn't handle as I know nothing about (even very basic) web architecture.

I would like to access to links to every courses under `https://www.coursera.org/browse/arts-and-humanities/history` with some filter (e.g. `language=english`): [Coursera history courses in English](https://www.coursera.org/browse/arts-and-humanities/history?facets=skillNameMultiTag%2CjobTitleMultiTag%2CdifficultyLevelTag%2Clanguages%3AEnglish%2CentityTypeTag%2CpartnerMultiTag%2CcategoryMultiTag%2CsubcategoryMultiTag%3Ahistory&sortField=).

After loading this webpage, many courses don't show before scrolling down. If I save the html file to local, I can find only 58 instances of `https://www.coursera.org/learn/`, the prefix to a course, but I'm suppose to get at least 128 of them.

So now how do I save a dynamically loaded webpage, either with Chrome or Python?

With @Rajat's code, the emulator could scroll down to bottom, but still the obtained html is incomplete.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver

current_dir=os.getcwd()
#download chromedriver for you operating system
driver = webdriver.Chrome(current_dir+'/chromedriver')
#place your url here
url="https://www.coursera.org/browse/arts-and-humanities/history?facets=skillNameMultiTag%2CjobTitleMultiTag%2CdifficultyLevelTag%2Clanguages%3AEnglish%2CentityTypeTag%2CpartnerMultiTag%2CcategoryMultiTag%2CsubcategoryMultiTag%3Ahistory&sortField="
driver.get(url)
count = 1200
step = 30
for _ in range(count):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, {});".format(step))
    time.sleep(0.01)

with open("output.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: With webapps that can get tricky as most of the dynamic content is usually handled and populated by js at runtime.

Comment: @varunagarwal Could you post an answer to elaborate?

Comment: using Python with Selenium you can control web browser (Chrome/Firefox) and scroll page so browser will load it - and then you can get HTML (using Selenium) and save in file using standard `open()`, `write()`, `close()` - but it will save only HTML, without image, js, css, etc.

Comment: @furas Yes I did exactly as what you said but still the obtained html is incomplete as before.

Comment: First: you should add this code at the beginnig. Second: you don't need BeautifulSoup to write HTML - `write(driver.page_source)`, Third: I will have to run code to see problem.

Comment: code scrolls 200 times but page is longer - it doesn't check if it is end of page. It would have to use `white True` loop and check if some element from footer is visible. But maybe you don't have to scroll - if javascript loads it from server then find url and load it from server too.

Comment: @furas From the emulator as I observe, scrolling 400 times would reach to the bottom but it doesn't help either.

Comment: I checked this page. It uses react.js - when you scroll down then it adds new elements at the bottom but it also remove elements at the top. When you scroll up then it adds element at the top but remove at the bottom. Maybe if you resize  window then it will have to display all elements at the same time. Or you will have to scroll down, get new elements from HTML and scroll again and get new elements again, etc.

Comment: @furas Is there any smart way to trace the data source (some JS files?) that keep updating this list?

Comment: in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox I see it POST some data to https://www.coursera.org/graphqlBatch and get JSON with courses. Firefox DevTool can generate cURL command and I tested it in console in Linux - it gives me JSON with courses. So you could try to do the same in Python with request or Selenium (maybe it will need some cookies). If you will get data in JSON then you can easly convert it to Python directory.

Comment: BTW: if you get cURL command from DevTool in Firefox/Chrome then you can convert it into Python code on page: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took @Gautam code and only rebuilt it.

First request gives only 100 items (even with limit=300) so using `start` I get next 28 items.

Using `json=` instead of `data=` I don't need `headers=` and `json.dump()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


def display(data):
    #print('len:', len(data))
    #print('len:', len(data[0]['data']['CatalogResultsV2Resource']['browseV2']['elements']))
    print('>>> len:', len(data[0]['data']['CatalogResultsV2Resource']['browseV2']['elements'][0]['courses']['elements']))

    items = data[0]['data']['CatalogResultsV2Resource']['browseV2']['elements'][0]['courses']['elements']

    for item in items:
        print(item['name'])

        #for key, value in item.items():
        #    print(key, value)
        #print('---')

#-----------------------------------------------------------

json_data = [{
    'operationName': 'catalogResultQuery',
    'variables': {
        'skip': False,
        'limit': 300,
        'start': '0',
        'sortField': '',
        'facets': [
            'skillNameMultiTag', 
            'jobTitleMultiTag', 
            'difficultyLevelTag', 
            'languages:English', 
            'entityTypeTag', 
            'partnerMultiTag', 
            'categoryMultiTag', 
            'subcategoryMultiTag:history'
        ]
    },
    'query': 'query catalogResultQuery($facets: [String!]!, $start: String!, $skip: Boolean = false, $sortField: String, $limit: Int) { CatalogResultsV2Resource { browseV2(facets: $facets, start: $start, limit: $limit, sortField: $sortField) @skip(if: $skip) { elements { label entries { id score courseId specializationId onDemandSpecializationId resourceName __typename } domainId subdomainId facets courses { elements { ...CourseFragment __typename } __typename } s12ns { elements { ...S12nFragment __typename } __typename } __typename } paging { total next __typename } __typename } __typename } } fragment CourseFragment on CoursesV1 { id slug name photoUrl s12nIds level workload courseDerivativesV2 { skillTags { skillName relevanceScore __typename } avgLearningHoursAdjusted commentCount averageFiveStarRating ratingCount __typename } partners { elements { name squareLogo classLogo logo __typename } __typename } __typename } fragment S12nFragment on OnDemandSpecializationsV1 { name id slug logo courseIds derivativeV2 { averageFiveStarRating avgLearningHoursAdjusted __typename } partners { elements { name squareLogo classLogo logo __typename } __typename } metadata { headerImage level __typename } courses { elements { courseDerivativesV2 { skillTags { skillName relevanceScore __typename } __typename } __typename } __typename } __typename } '
}]

url = 'https://www.coursera.org/graphqlBatch'

#headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
#r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data, verify=False)

# --- it gives first 100 items ---

r = requests.post(url, json=json_data, verify=False)
data = r.json()
display(data)

# --- it gives next 28 items ---

json_data[0]['variables']['start'] = str(100) # it has to be string, not integer

r = requests.post(url, json=json_data, verify=False)
data = r.json()
display(data)
```

Start of result:

```
>>> len: 100
Buddhism and Modern Psychology 
English Composition I
Fashion as Design
The Modern World, Part One: Global History from 1760 to 1910
Indigenous Canada
Understanding Einstein: The Special Theory of Relativity
Terrorism and Counterterrorism: Comparing Theory and Practice
Magic in the Middle Ages
The Ancient Greeks
Introduction to Ancient Egypt and Its Civilization
```

End of result:

```
>>> len: 28
Theatre and Globalization
ART of the MOOC: Arte Público y Pedagogía 
The Music of the Rolling Stones, 1962-1974
Soul Beliefs: Causes and Consequences - Unit 2: Belief Systems
The Making of the US President: A Short History in Five Elections
Cities are back in town : sociologie urbaine pour un monde globalisé
Toledo: Deciphering Secrets of Medieval Spain
Russia and Nuclear Arms Control
Espace mondial, a French vision of Global studies
Religious Transformation in Early China: the Period of Division
Patrick Henry: Forgotten Founder
A la recherche du Grand Paris
Burgos: Deciphering Secrets of Medieval Spain
Journey Conversations: Weaving Knowledge and Action
Structuring Values in Modern China
Religion and Thought in Modern China: the Song, Jin, and Yuan
宇宙之旅：展现生命 (Journey of the Universe: The Unfolding of Life)
The Worldview of Thomas Berry:  The Flourishing of the Earth Community
Science and Technology in the Silla Cultural Heritage
世界空间、法国视角下的国���研究
Fundamentals of the Chinese character writing (Part 1)
Understanding China, 1700-2000: A Data Analytic Approach, Part 2
"Espace mondial" الرؤية الفرنسية للدراسات العالمية
Searching for the Grand Paris
宇宙之旅：对话 (Journey of the Universe: Weaving Knowledge and Action)
Contemporary India 
Thomas Berry的世界观：地球社区的繁荣 (The Worldview of Thomas Berry: The Flourishing of the Earth Community)
"Making" Progress Teach-Out
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use selenium web driver i use chromedriver for this work, it will open your webpage and perform scroll down function, you just need to identify some condition for implement scroll down.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver

current_dir=os.getcwd()
#download chromedriver for you operating system
driver = webdriver.Chrome(current_dir+'/chromedriver')
#place your url here
url="https://stackoverflow.com"
driver.get(url)
#you can use how many scroll do you want using loop
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(count*1400))
time.sleep(2)

inner_html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(inner_html,'html.parser')
```

here soup will contain all html data of this webpage

Comment: Hi Rajat, thanks for your answer but it didn't work for me. Could you check my update?

Comment: yes, I will check updates. As per my knowledge might be your webpage required some login checks or it is written in javascript.
if it requires login you can log in using send_keys method
example:
first, identify the input field from inspecting element
email=driver.find_element_by_id('loginid')
email.clear()
email.send_keys("xyz@gmail.com")

Comment: No logging is not required.

Answer (score 1):

It seems they are using graphql for fetching the results. It also seems there is no kind of authentication on the site. You can use a simple post call using any of your favorite tool ( python, curl, postman etc ) to get the result. Since your original code is in python, here is a simple code snippet using python :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import json
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def getHeadersb345e918473d():
    result={}
    result['content-type']='application/json'
    return result

def json_data_e6084285():
    result=[]
    result_item0={}
    result_item0['query']='query catalogResultQuery($facets: [String!]!, $start: String!, $skip: Boolean = false, $sortField: String, $limit: Int) { CatalogResultsV2Resource { browseV2(facets: $facets, start: $start, limit: $limit, sortField: $sortField) @skip(if: $skip) { elements { label entries { id score courseId specializationId onDemandSpecializationId resourceName __typename } domainId subdomainId facets courses { elements { ...CourseFragment __typename } __typename } s12ns { elements { ...S12nFragment __typename } __typename } __typename } paging { total next __typename } __typename } __typename } } fragment CourseFragment on CoursesV1 { id slug name photoUrl s12nIds level workload courseDerivativesV2 { skillTags { skillName relevanceScore __typename } avgLearningHoursAdjusted commentCount averageFiveStarRating ratingCount __typename } partners { elements { name squareLogo classLogo logo __typename } __typename } __typename } fragment S12nFragment on OnDemandSpecializationsV1 { name id slug logo courseIds derivativeV2 { averageFiveStarRating avgLearningHoursAdjusted __typename } partners { elements { name squareLogo classLogo logo __typename } __typename } metadata { headerImage level __typename } courses { elements { courseDerivativesV2 { skillTags { skillName relevanceScore __typename } __typename } __typename } __typename } __typename } '
    variables={}
    variables['skip']=False
    facets=[]
    facets.append('skillNameMultiTag')
    facets.append('jobTitleMultiTag')
    facets.append('difficultyLevelTag')
    facets.append('languages:English')
    facets.append('entityTypeTag')
    facets.append('partnerMultiTag')
    facets.append('categoryMultiTag')
    facets.append('subcategoryMultiTag:history')
    variables['facets']=facets
    variables['limit']=300
    variables['start']='0'
    variables['sortField']=''
    result_item0['variables']=variables
    result_item0['operationName']='catalogResultQuery'
    result.append(result_item0)
    return result

url='https://www.coursera.org/graphqlBatch'
r=requests.post(url, headers=getHeadersb345e918473d(), data=json.dumps(json_data_e6084285()), verify=False )
print unicode(r.text)
```

You can tinker with the `limit` and `start` values to get the desired result.